# Include row number in query result (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I think each row in sql server is given a unique number.  How can I include that in my SQL query results?

Comment: Typically the first field in the table--possibly named 'id' or something like that--is the primary key, which is usually an integer that increases by 1 for every new line... so it's like a row-number. But we would have to know how the table is organized to say whether there is an id field and, if so, how to retrieve it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you are referring to the row number provided by Management Studio when you run a query, there is no way to get that because it does not really exist. Management Studio generates that on the fly. You can however, recreate a sequential number using the [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) ranking function if you are using SQL Server 2005 or later. Note you should never assume the database will return the rows in a specified order unless you include an Order By statement. So your query might look like:

```
Select ....
    , Row_Number() Over ( Order By T.SomeColumn ) As Num
From Table As T
Order By T.SomeColumn
```

The Order By in the Over clause is used to determine the order for creating the sequential numbers. The Order By clause at the end of the query is used to determine the order of the rows in the output (i.e. the order for the sequence number and the order of the rows can be different).

Comment: Nice :). I did row_number over my primary key column. That way i got a sequential number from 1 without any gaps (even if row is deleted).

Comment: How can we achieve the same in MySQL

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan - Same way: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

Comment: Yeah I tried buy somewhere it does not work for me and I have gone with Offset

Answer (score 3):

The uniqueness in your result will always be your primary key.

But there is something called ROW_NUMBER function that can be used as unique identity of row in a specific result.

```
SELECT zip,city,state,latitude,longitude,timezone,dst,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY zip) AS num
          FROM dbo.zipcode;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use this one....

`DCount('Column_Name','Table_Name','Column_Name <= ' & [Column_Name]) as SR`

Comment: `DCount()` is not a function in SQL Server.