# How to get ROW_NUMBER() in SQL?

Tags: sql, firebird

I tried to get the row number using `ROW_NUMBER()` but it shows the following error:

> can't format message 13:896 -- message file C:\WINDOWS\firebird.msg
>   not found. Dynamic SQL Error. SQL error code = -104. Token unknown -
>   line 2, column 66.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT  avg(CSIDTL.RATING) ,SVD.SVCADVISORNAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY avg(CSIDTL.RATING) )
        FROM T_APPT_BOOKING_MSTR MSTR ,T_APPT_CSI_SURVEY CSI,T_APPT_CSI_SURVEY_DTL CSIDTL,
        T_SVC_SVCADVISOR_MASTER SVD
        WHERE MSTR.APPTBKID = CSI.APPTBKID
        AND CSI.CSI_SURVERYID = CSIDTL.CSI_SURVERYID
        AND SVD.SVCADVISORID = MSTR.SVCADVISORID
        AND CSI.FEEDBACK_STATUS = 'Y'
        AND CSIDTL.question ='Service Advisor'
        GROUP BY SVD.SVCADVISORNAME
        ORDER by avg(CSIDTL.RATING)
```

Comment: what version of firebird?

Comment: I'm not sure you can `ORDER BY avg` inside `OVER`...

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344863/how-can-i-get-the-row-number-in-sql-query) previously asked question might help you.

Comment: try this before but doesn't work

Comment: Which version are you using? Is it one from before ROW_NUMBER() was introduced?

Comment: You need to upgrade to Firebird 3.0 it has support for window functions.

Comment: first update your client library and firebird.msg file and then post error message you got

Answer (score 9):

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function was introduced with Firebird 3.0, released just few days ago. See release notes, chapter [Window (Analytical) Functions](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs.html) for exact syntax. The error you get suggests you're using an older version of Firebird which doesn't have this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Example for Firebird 3.0+

```
SELECT row_number() over(), t.* FROM test t
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this in Firebird 2.5

Reference: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq343/

```
SELECT rdb$get_context('USER_TRANSACTION', 'row#') as row_number, DUMMY, A.*
FROM your_table A
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT rdb$set_context('USER_TRANSACTION', 'row#',
COALESCE(CAST(rdb$get_context('USER_TRANSACTION', 'row#') AS INTEGER), 0) + 1) AS dummy
FROM rdb$database) dummy
```

Answer (score 0):

Other alternative in Firebird 2.5 is use of generators

```
CREATE GENERATOR tmp$rn;
UPDATE my_table t SET t.id_field = (SELECT FIRST 1 NEXT VALUE FOR tmp$rn AS "row_number"
FROM my_table ORDER BY another_field1 DESC, another_field2 DESC);
DROP GENERATOR tmp$rn;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful,

Reference
[Firebird 3.0 Language Reference - 10.4. Ranking Functions](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-windowfuncs-rankfuncs)

- Available in :DSQL, PSQL
- Result type  :BIGINT

Syntax

```sql
ROW_NUMBER () OVER <window-specification>
```

Returns the sequential row number in the partition of the result set, where 1 is the first row in each of the partitions.