# how to delete repeated values in UNION query using count

Tags: sql, firebird

Hello I have been trying to delete a repeated value on the following UNION query with the following results (image). How can I filter out the value LW_ID=8232 with AANTALLN =0. I need to find a way taht if in the first query AANTALLN >0 is found, then on the second part of the union query not insert it again. Thanks  " [image]

```html
With LESEENHEIDLOOPBAAN as (
  SELECT 
    LE_AGENDA_FK, 
    LE_CODE, 
    LE_ID, 
    LE_KLAS_FK, 
    LE_KLASPARTITIE_FK, 
    LE_OMSCHRIJVING, 
    LE_VERANDERDDOOR, 
    LE_VERANDERDOP, 
    Count(LH_ID) As AantalLln 
  FROM 
    LESEENHEID 
    INNER JOIN LOOPBAANLESEENHEID on (LH_LESEENHEID_FK = LE_ID) 
    INNER JOIN LOOPBAAN ON (LH_LOOPBAAN_FK = LB_ID) 
  WHERE 
    (
      '2022/09/28' BETWEEN LB_VAN 
      AND LB_TOT
    ) 
    AND (
      LE_ID in (8277, 8276, 8232)
    ) 
  GROUP BY 
    LE_AGENDA_FK, 
    LE_CODE, 
    LE_ID, 
    LE_KLAS_FK, 
    LE_KLASPARTITIE_FK, 
    LE_OMSCHRIJVING, 
    LE_VERANDERDDOOR, 
    LE_VERANDERDOP
), 
LESEENHEIDLOOPBAANNULL AS (
  SELECT 
    LE_AGENDA_FK, 
    LE_CODE, 
    LE_ID, 
    LE_KLAS_FK, 
    LE_KLASPARTITIE_FK, 
    LE_OMSCHRIJVING, 
    LE_VERANDERDDOOR, 
    LE_VERANDERDOP, 
    0 As AantalLln 
  FROM 
    LESEENHEID 
  where 
    LE_ID in (8277, 8276, 8232) 
    and EXISTS (
      SELECT 
        * 
      FROM 
        LESEENHEIDLOOPBAAN 
    )
) 
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  LESEENHEIDLOOPBAAN 
UNION 
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  LESEENHEIDLOOPBAANNULL ROWS 1000
```

Comment: `I need to find a way that if in the first query AANTALLN >0 is found` this can also be a solution... remove all the rows with this value less than maximum per LE_ID. Granted, in FB 2.5 (without window functions) this would not be very efifcient, so i would not provide options here. But you may find similar "select from select" in other questions. 
When inner one is direct orderd select from table-  it is obvious. But since your primary query is already complex - perhaps this approacj would be wayt too heavy on FB2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out using ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT * FROM (   
SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY LW_ID ORDER BY AANTALLN DESC) AS RN
     ,* FROM 
      (
       SELECT * FROM 
           LESEENHEIDLOOPBAAN 
           UNION 
           SELECT 
           * 
           FROM 
           LESEENHEIDLOOPBAANNULL ROWS 1000
      )
    ) 
    ) WHERE RN = 1
```

This way you eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY LW_ID ORDER BY AANTALLN DESC) AS RN,* seems not working in firebird 2.5. Can you clarify, thanks. They are not really duplicates, the two rows with LE_ID=8232 have different values of AANTALLN, i need to filter out the ones that have value of 0.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733521/how-to-get-row-number-in-sql) of a previously asked question might help you. Nevertheless, it seems like windows functions were introduced only on firebird 3.0.

Comment: @TonathiuRedrovan then please edit your question and put the proper tag, documenting Firebird version you need. As of now your question is not, answer working in any Firebird version fits